# how to cover/stretch an image across the entire page css/html?

Tags: html, css, background-image

```
body{
    background-image: url("web.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the code i tried, but it is not working and i also tried to use screen width as default width for the entire image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background size by using `background-size` property. In case of covering the whole page please use `background-size: cover;`.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1080/1920");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Your content here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the image as asked, you have to use **background-size** along with its attributes
(*try these three and then select the one suitable for you*)

```css
body{
    background-image: url("webp.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* used to set the image to fit 100% of the screen's width and height*/
}

body{
        background-image: url("web.png");/* To cover the screen */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
body{
        background-image: url("web.png");/*contains the image within the screen with with proper scale of the image*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
}
```